# Ideal order of GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER and glTexImage2D

Tags: opengl

In all the examples, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER and GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER are always set before glTexImage2D is called. Is there any reason for this?

I know that they have to be set (or you have to make mipmaps) before the texture is usable, but is there anything wrong with setting them after glTexImage2D?

Examples:

```
GL11.glTexParameteri(target, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexParameteri(target, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexImage2D(target, 0, GL_RGBA8, t_width, t_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureBuffer);
```

vs

```
GL11.glTexImage2D(target, 0, GL_RGBA8, t_width, t_height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureBuffer);
GL11.glTexParameteri(target, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
GL11.glTexParameteri(target, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope, shouldn't make any difference. Those should only have any effect when the texture is sampled, which comes much later.

Comment: What this is how the OpenGL spec defines it, there used to be buggy implementations, which would respect the texture paramters (especially filtering) only if they were set before calling glTexImage. This is probably the main reason why you can still see this pattern in tutorials. In modern OpenGL we got sampler objects, which got us rid of such problems.